# Calling Spring Integration transformers dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-integration

I am new in Spring integration and working on a SI project. I am doing a simple job of getting message from a channel (fromAdapter), calling a transformer and sending the output to another channel (toQueue). The below code is used in the SI configuration file ----

```
<int:channel id="fromAdapter"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="toQueue">  
</int:channel>  
<bean id="trans" class="src.MyTransformer"></bean>  
<int:transformer input-channel="fromAdapter" output-channel="toQueue" ref="trans"></int:transformer>
```

However, now I have a slightly complex requirement. Instead of always sending the message to one transformer,based on some value of the message, I want to send the message to any one of 6 transformers. How can this be implemented?

Comment: I think some of the tags you chose for this question are misleading: "dependency injection"... might be; but "spring-mvc" or "java" -- I can't see that.

Comment: No i dont think so, Im working with SI in java and core Spring, so better to include the core Spring and Java audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare those 6 transformers as subscribers to a single *point-to-point* channel and by default it will use a round robin dispatching strategy (it will only invoke a single transformer for each message, but it will always pick the next transformer in the list and then cycle).

In your case, you should simply declare all those transformers to use the exact same input and output channels and the above will automagically happen.

---

To pick the transformer based on some attribute of your message, you can use a `recipient-list-router` and define a `selector-expression` for each `recipient` in the list in order to match a particular kind of message. Also, for each recipient you should use a different channel name. Then each of those channels will be used as input by the desired transformer:

```
<recipient-list-router input-channel="fromAdapter" default-output-channel="toQueue">
    <recipient channel="t1" selector-expression="payload.someFlag"/>
    <recipient channel="t2" selector-expression="headers.someOtherFlag"/>
</recipient-list-router>

<transformer input-channel="t1" ref="transformer1" method="transform"/>
<transformer input-channel="t2" ref="transformer2" method="transform"/>
```

Keep in mind that with this approach, a message could match more than one selector expression so it's up to you to provide mutually exclusive expressions.

Or, if you are willing to write some infrastructure code, you can write your own implementation of `LoadBalancingStrategy` and provide that to your point-to-point channel. Your strategy will then be responsible for picking the right handler for each message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this does not solve by problem completely. I do-not want to use round robin strategy. I want to do the transformer routing based on some value in the message. For example, for all messages with a field country set to USA I want to invoke USATransformer, for all messages with the field country set to France I want to invoke FranceTransformer and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: I must have skipped "based on some value..." and jumped to "...to any one of 6 transformers" :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hi Costi..thanks for your support. It will be very grateful if you could edit your answer to this ..-:)

Comment: Just did... let me know if this works for you as it's... kind of untested :)

Answer (score 2):

The recipient list router will work, and may be appropriate if you want to send a message to multiple transformers, but if not, you'll have to be careful to make the selector expressions mutually exclusive. Maybe one of the simpler routers might be more appropriate. For example...

```
<header-value-router input-channel="routingChannel" header-name="foo">
    <mapping value="1" channel="channel1" />
    <mapping value="2" channel="channel2" />
</header-value-router>
```

or

```
<router id="spelRouter" input-channel="expressionRouter"
                    expression="payload.someProperty"
        default-output-channel="defaultChannelForExpression"
        resolution-required="false">
    <mapping value="foo" channel="fooChannelForExpression"/>
    <mapping value="bar" channel="barChannelForExpression"/>
</router>
```